# multiple swiper.js sliders with thumbnail navigation on same page

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

If I have multiple swiper.js sliders on a page then only the first slider works.
I used this slider as a guideline: https://swiperjs.com/demos#thumbs-gallery-loop
I have a lot of pages with multiple sliders, so a solution where you don't have to add classes or copy a lot of javascript would be good.

I think my JavaScript code is wrong.

I have found a solution how to run multiple sliders without thumbnail navigation on one page. The code: https://codepen.io/johannes-bichlmayr/pen/JjZVqqR

With thumbnail navigation it is very difficult. My current code: https://codepen.io/johannes-bichlmayr/pen/KKeYjgP
It does not work very well.

This was my first JavaScript code that works very well with one slider per page:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  loop: false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide').length / 2,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  loop: false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper,
  },
});
```

With the code you can run two sliders **without thumbnail** navigation on one page:

```
  // declare Swiper.js .classes
const myCustomSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-container');

// declare navigation arrows classes
const mySliderPrev = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-button-prev');
const mySliderNext = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-button-next');

for( i=0; i< myCustomSlider.length; i++ ) {
// add special class with number to each Swiper.js slider and its nabigation arrows  
  myCustomSlider[i].classList.add('swiper-container-' + i);
  mySliderPrev[i].classList.add('swiper-button-prev-' + i);
  mySliderNext[i].classList.add('swiper-button-next-' + i);
  
  
     var slider = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'slide',
    
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
});
  }
```

I am working on the code right now:

```
  // declare Swiper.js .classes
const myCustomSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.mySwiper2');

// declare navigation arrows classes
const mySliderPrev = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-button-prev');
const mySliderNext = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-button-next');

for( i=0; i< myCustomSlider.length; i++ ) {
// add special class with number to each Swiper.js slider and its nabigation arrows  
  myCustomSlider[i].classList.add('mySwiper2-' + i);
  mySliderPrev[i].classList.add('swiper-button-prev-' + i);
  mySliderNext[i].classList.add('swiper-button-next-' + i);
  
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  loop: false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper,
  },
});
  }

  // declare Swiper.js .classes
const myCustomSliderThumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.mySwiper');

for( i=0; i< myCustomSliderThumbs.length; i++ ) {
// add special class with number to each Swiper.js slider and its nabigation arrows  
  myCustomSliderThumbs[i].classList.add('mySwiper-' + i);

var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  loop: false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide').length / 2,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
  }
```